# Vue.js - Laravel User Id

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Im working on a project to learn Vue.js with Laravel.
I created a simple tasks application, where its possible to create, modify, mark as done, and delete tasks.

I wish to make it user individual, so i ran artisan make:auth to create the auth template.
Added column : user_id to tasks table.
In the Index method of TaskController instead of -
return Task::all();
I tried to do -
return Task::where('user_id', Auth::id() );
but its not working as I wish...
If instead of Auth::id() I put 1 for example, it does return the tasks for user id 1.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Are you logged in?

Comment: yes, i`m logged in. Also tried to re-login, still nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Check in your code that `Auth::id()` is actually returning the user's ID - it's likely that your user isn't authenticated and is therefore returning `null`, so the query doesn't work as you expect.

Also, if you set up your associations correctly (that is, a user `hasMany` tasks) then you could simplify the code by using the association instead.

```
return Auth::user()->tasks;

// Achieves same result as...

return Task::where('user_id', Auth::id())->get();
```